# Dynamic Component Select Radio Selected Value

Tags: dynamic-visualforce, selectoption, selectradio

I have built a dyanmic component as selectOption (select radio with select option values).  I need to know how can I access the selected value? (which radio button is selected?)

Below is my code

VF

```
<apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!CustomInsuranceProducts}"/>
```

Apex class

```
public Component.Apex.selectRadio getCustomInsuranceProducts(){                  
        Component.Apex.selectRadio myCustomRadio = new Component.Apex.selectRadio();

        myCustomRadio.id = 'Insurance_Package';                     
        for(ApplicantProductWrapper myappprod : mapApplicantProduct.get(Constants.INSURANCE)) {
            Component.Apex.selectOption so = new Component.Apex.selectOption();
            so.itemValue = myappprod.applicantProduct.Product__c;                
            Component.Apex.OutputText output = new Component.Apex.OutputText();
            output.expressions.value = '{!$Label.' + myappprod.Prod.description__c + '}';
            string labelValue = string.valueOf(output.value);                    
            so.itemLabel = labelValue;
            myCustomRadio.childComponents.add(so);
    }       
       return myCustomRadio;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a `value` parameter of the `selectRadio` component and assign some string variable to it:

```
public String selectedValue { get; set; }

public Component.Apex.selectRadio getCustomInsuranceProducts(){                  
    Component.Apex.selectRadio myCustomRadio = new Component.Apex.selectRadio();
    myCustomRadio.id = 'Insurance_Package';

    selectedValue = [SELECT Id from .....];

    myCustomRadio.expressions.value = '{!selectedValue}';
```

Comment: what does selectedValue hold?  Which value should I assign to it?  I do not know what is the selected value

Comment: @BruceLee It is a variable that is associated with this selectRadio component. It holds selected radio button value. [Read more about `value` parameter of the `apex:selectRadio` component](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_selectRadio.htm).

Comment: Yup, it indeed worked.  I had to assign the appropriate value from the record to this variable in the for loop. 

selectedValue = map.get(package);